# How to connect Intellij IDEA 2019.2.3 and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea

I would like to ask where I should add configuration of servers in Intellij IDEA 2019.2.3. I already check it in older version and it is not the same.

I tried to connect it like in this tutorial 
https://adilmca.wordpress.com/2016/02/20/installation-and-configuration-of-jetbrains-ides-for-mongodb/

In new version when I press add server there is no Mongo. Is it possible? Where can I find it?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You should append your `add server` screenshot, and the idea.log file here.

Answer (score 1):

Tried it on IDEA 2019.2.3, it works fine here. It's an 3rd-party plugin. You can use it by accessing: `View->Tool Windows-> Mongo Explorer`. See the plugin [docs](https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea) for more information.

[image]

PS: There are some [issues](https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea/issues/278) in 2019.1+, and the author of [Mongo Plugin](https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea) seems out of contact for a while.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this plugin [Mongo DB Browser](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/20002-mongo-db-browser) for latest versions (2021.3+) of IDEs